# Java Brick Breaker Game paddle leaving a trace

Tags: java

I'm creating a brick breaker game the paddle moving but the paddle makes a trail behind it and it's hard to see where it is here's the code. I'm already tried to rewrite all but still doesnt work.

```
public class GamePlay extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
Block bola = new Block(237,435,25,25,"bola.png");
Block paddle = new Block(175,480,150,25,"paddle.png");
GamePlay(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    paddle.draw(g,this);
}
public void update() {
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);{
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                update();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && paddle.x < (getWidth() - paddle.width)){
      paddle.x += 15;
  }
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      paddle.x -= 15;
    }

}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I want the paddle able to move, the paddle move but it leaving a trace